# Upgrading my MSI Internal RAM

Tags: memory

I have [MSI MS-1454](http://www.msiwhitebook.com/product_spec.asp?model=MS-1454-ID1) model with 2GB RAM.  I want to upgrade it with G.Skill DDR3 8GB RAM, but I’m not sure if it is compatible with my laptop model. How do I determine this?

Comment: Its not.  The specification you link to clearly indicate the maxium memory supported is 4GB

Comment: Well, the question shouldn't have been modified from a shopping question, then a link the specification added.  The author's intent changed entirely by doing that.

Comment: @Raldenors what CPU does your laptop have? Also I would suggest excluding the brand name of the RAM and only list the specs so it cannot be construed as a shopping question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official manufacturer specs for the [MSI MS-1454](http://www.msiwhitebook.com/product_spec.asp?model=MS-1454-ID1), maximum RAM it can handle is 4GB with 2GB in each slot:

> SO-DIMM slots x 2 for DDR3 1066/800 MHz
>
> Max.: 4GB (Up to 2GB each slot)

Also, you just mention “G.Skill DDR3 8GB RAM” and not much else. The reality is not all RAM is created the same and just because a stick of RAM is DDR3 or has the same form factor does not mean you can just stick it into something and hope it works.

You need to *always check your manufacturer’s specs* and then make sure you purchase RAM that is compatible with your machine. And if the RAM is not explicitly specified as compatible for your machine, you need to still match the detailed specs—2GB max per slot of DDR3 1066/800 MHz RAM, 204 pin SODIMM—or else chances of you buying incompatible RAM just because it “seems right” are pretty high.

Answer (score 0):

As [Giacomo1968 pointed out in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/886885/167207), the manufacturer's specs list 4 GB (up to 2 GB each slot) as the maximum.

However, the published specs may be conservative simply because higher-density memory modules were not readily available for testing during product development. For example, Apple claims a maximum memory capacity of 4 GB for their mid-2010 MacBook, but [that MacBook model actually supports up to 16 GB RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook#Model_specifications_3).

The MSI MS-1454 has an Intel HM55 chipset, meaning the memory controller is on-die on the CPU. If your CPU supports more than 4 GB RAM, it's possible the laptop will support more RAM, although a BIOS update may be required. That said, there is no guarantee that your laptop supports more than 4 GB. I would suggest asking MSI support if there is a BIOS update available for your laptop, and if you know anyone with a 4 GB or larger DDR3 SO-DIMM I'd suggest testing your laptop with their RAM (assuming it's not soldered to the motherboard) before buying any 4 GB or larger SO-DIMMs for your laptop.